# Function call with i + 1, ++i implementation difference?

Tags: java, optimization, increment, function-calls

Just a quickie about Java, and let me say this first: I'm not worried about this due to performance optimization, just curious about the behind the scenes stuff in general. Since I found nothing to this I assume they are equivalent in every respect, but just to be sure:

In a recursive function `foo(int i)`, or I guess in generel in a function call, is there a difference between `foo(++i)` and `foo(i + 1)`? I know the result is the same, but I thought the one with `++i` might do some extrawork in the background because it is an assignment? So maybe it creates an `(anonymous field) = i` in the background which gets incremented and then referenced?
Or does the compiler just optimize `++i` away to `i + 1`?

My understanding is a bit fuzzy as you see, so help would be appreciated.

**EDIT to clarify:**

At first this was due to a recursive function e.g.

```
public static int foo(int i) {
        return (i >= 4) ? 0 
            : i + foo(++i);
    }
```

The "functions in general"-part came in the middle of writing the question and, as remarked, makes this ambiguous etc. Hope this clarifies everything.

Comment: I suggest you to use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html on two simple classes (or on a class with two methods) each with one of the two approaches, you will get a better understanding of the whole thing rather than reading an answer here ^^

Comment: The JIT compiler could indeed make such an optimisation on the basis that `i` is dead after the increment. Whether it actually makes such an optimisation is another question. The Java-to-bytecode compiler will not optimise that for you, though; the increment will be in the bytecode. It's 100% up to the JIT compiler to optimise.

Comment: *"I know the result is the same"* Depends on the code. If you access `i` more than once, then the result is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the answer is not about semantics but about performance at the machine level after the IR has been optimized, translated into machine instructions, I would say, "no unless measured and proven otherwise."

It's very unlikely that there will be a performance difference after all the optimizations are made between `f(++i)` and `f(i+1)`, assuming your code is such that you can actually consider these as alternatives (assuming the state of `i` ceases to become relevant after the function call).

It's just basic hardware and compiler design, the cost of instructions for memory already stored in a register, the simplicity of optimizing away this code to the same machine code in even a semi-competent compiler (and I'd think Java's JIT would at least be that). It's a very basic nature of a compiler to recognize unnecessary side effects and eliminate them outright (actually one of the reasons why artificial micro-level benchmarks can be misleading unless they're written very carefully in a way that prevents the optimizer from skipping certain code outright). Among the easiest side effects to eliminate is a case like this, where we're incrementing a variable, `i` but not depending on the state change afterwards.

It seems unlikely to have any real impact on performance. Of course the ultimate way is to look at the final resulting machine code (not the bytecode IR but the actual final machine code) or measure and profile it. But I'd be quite shocked, to say the least, if one is faster than the other, and it would tend to make me think that the compiler is doing a pretty poor job in either instruction selection or register allocation.

That said, if one actually was (remote chance) faster than the other, I think you have it backwards. `++i` would likely require less work since it can just increment a value in a register. `++i` is a unary operation on one operand, and that works well with registers which are mutable. `i + 1` is an expression that requires that `i` be treated as immutable and would call for a second register (but only in a really horrible kind of toy compiler scenario that didn't optimize anything, though in that case we're also compiling this expression in the context of a function call and have to consider things like stack spills, so even a toy compiler might make these somewhat equivalent).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the execution of `foo(++i)` and `foo(i + 1)`: the value of the parameter passed to `foo` is the same.

However, in the former case, the local variable `i` is increased by one; in the latter case, it retains its original value.

So if you make the same method call twice, there is a difference:

```
foo(++i);
foo(++i);  // Invoke with i 1 greater than before.
```

is different from

```
foo(i + 1);
foo(i + 1);  // Invoke with the same argument
```

As such, in general, the compiler cannot optimize anything away, because they have different semantics.

Comment: That's not answering the OP's question, which is whether the `++i` gets optimised to `i + 1` on the basis that `i` is dead after the call. Of course the OP already knows what `++i` does.

Comment: Also, some patience please: I downvote first and explain later, not the other way around. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young OP asks "is there a difference between foo(++i) and foo(i + 1)". And I am answering yes.

Comment: The OP's question could be clearer, but if you read carefully, you'll see what's actually being asked.

Comment: "I guess in generel in a function call, is there a difference between foo(++i) and foo(i + 1)?" In general, there is a difference.

Comment: True, "in general" there is a difference, and I think the OP should clarify the question to narrow it down. I'll retract my downvote on the basis of your "in general".

Answer (score 2):

Beside the other comments about the value of `i` after using the prefix increment. There is a small difference in the generated bytecode. See below the simplified results.

foo(++i) compiled to

```
iinc
iload_1
invokestatic
```

foo(i + 1) compiled to

```
iload_1                                              
iconst_1                                             
iadd                                                 
invokestatic
```

Comment: The bytecode is of course different. `javac` in general does not optimise the bytecode that's generated; it leaves the optimisation work to the JIT compiler. The question of interest is whether the JIT compiler actually does optimise out the increment.

Answer (score 1):

yes, ++i consists of two operations addition and assignment.Since, you don't need i later, i+1 is better to use rather than ++i.

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is used after `foo(++i)`, the value will have been changed

If you process `i` after `foo(i + 1)`, the value will not have been changed

```
foo(int i)
{
    //process stuff A
    foo(i + 1);
    //process stuff B
}

bar(int i)
{
    //process stuff A
    bar(i + 1);
    //process stuff B
}
```

Depending on what is in `//process stuff B`, you may either want to use `i + 1` and have the value of `i` be the same, or `++i` and have `i` be incremented

Comment: That's not answering the OP's question, which is whether the `++i` gets optimised to `i + 1` on the basis that `i` is dead after the call. Of course the OP already knows what `++i` does.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young it depends completely on what is called after the recursive looping

Comment: Of course it does. But the OP's question centres around the `i`-is-dead-after-`++i` case.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Where in the OP does it say that it is the last instruction in the method?

Comment: The question does not say that it's the last instruction. That's not relevant, anyway: it revolves around the OP's assumption that `i`'s value is not used after the `++i`. In such a case, the JIT compiler could indeed optimise out the increment.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Assuming what people want is a bad idea.  We can only really go off of what is being asked